# Objective C: How to add a red color tab to a tab bar controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbar

I would like to create a center red tab button (like in Pinterest) as seen in the screenshot below

[image]

Any advise on how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom button on top of the UITabBar.

See http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/

Answer (score 2):

```
    //in ur view didload    
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad]; 

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 49);

    UIView *viw = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"urRedColorImage.png"];

    UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:image];

    viw.backgroundColor = color;

    [color release];

    [[self tabBar] insertSubview:viw atIndex:0];

    [viw release];

}
```

Comment: yes, and eventually add a tap gesture recognizer to "viw" to get the tap gesture over the "fake" button